# How can I associate an user to an account using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a model named "User", and i use devise to create accounts. When some user signs up he is asked to insert an email and password, after that i would like to redirect the page to the User creation form, where the user would insert more detail, like name, age , etc... And the User model would have a account_id field that would be initialized to current_account.id at creation. I would like to know whats the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a user_id in the Account class, so an Account belongs to a User, rather than the other way around. This is for the associations to make more sense, like so:

*models/user.rb*

```
class User
  has_one :account
```

*models/account.rb*

```
class Account
  belongs_to :user
```

Make sure you generate a migration for adding a user_id to the account table!!

Then you will need to override the devise registrations controller. Firstly we edit the routes - you will see I also included :account as a nested resource (singular). That way the URL will be nicer e.g /users/6/account/edit

*config/routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

resources :users do 
  resource :account
end
```

And then create the controller. We will override two methods here, the 'create' action, where we will build the users Account within it. Then want to override the after_sign_up_path_for method to redirect to the edit account page. ** Note: This is for devise 3.0.3. If you are using a different version, look at their github for the registrations code.

*controllers/registrations_controller.rb*

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      resource.build_account(:user_id => resource.id) # code to create account
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  protected

  # override the after signup path to your desired route, e.g
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_account_path(resource.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: I just played with this locally and they were some minor errors and omissions. I have updated my answer with tested code.